# function call with one argument in typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have this function that triggers other functions depending on the service selected:

```
const serviceCalc = (service: "standard" | "premium" | "excelium") => {

    if (service === "standard") {
        return standard();
    }

    if (service === "premium") {
        return premium();
    }

    if (service === "excelium") {
        return excelium();
    }

}
```

What I'm trying to do is call the serviceCalc function but without having to specify the service that was selected in the form as a parameter of serviceCalc:

```
const commercial = () => {
    const totElevators = (document.getElementById("comminput_number-of-elevators") as HTMLInputElement); 
    const cages = totElevators.value;
    (document.getElementById('output_elevator-amount') as HTMLInputElement).value = cages;
    serviceCalc()             
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do you expect `serviceCalc()` to do if you don't specify a parameter?

Comment: my goal is that if somebody clicks the standard option, than standard parameter is passed to serviceCalc, and same thing for premium or excelium.

Comment: Look into [default parameters](https://www.typescripttutorial.net/typescript-tutorial/typescript-default-parameters/)

Comment: @user17710829 Then you should pass in the correct parameter for which option is selected. In fact, I'd say that `serviceCalc()` isn't needed. Each option should directly call `standard()`, `premium()` or `excelium()` directly.

Comment: Side note: don't use `document.getElementById()` in React. In fact, you should not interact with the DOM directly. Instead, use components and state.